# Does the location background mode work in swift when the app is terminated?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, cllocationmanager

Right now, I'm trying to implement the location background mode for my app. When the user location is updated, I'm going to schedule a notification (eventually I'll schedule them conditionally, but for right now I'm just scheduling them so I know it works). I have the following code:

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.first {
        currentLocation = location
    }
    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background {
    // if the app is in the background
         let notif = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notif.title = "Location was updated"
    var message = " "
    notif.body = message
    let identifier = String(arc4random())
    var dc = DateComponents()
    var date = Date()
    date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 3, to: date)!
    dc.hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date)
    dc.minute = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: date)
    dc.second = Calendar.current.component(.second, from: date)
    let notifTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dc, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: notif, trigger: notifTrigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        } else {
            print("Notification scheduled!")
        }
    })
```

This works great when the app is in the background, but when the app gets terminated, my function isn't called, and the notifications aren't getting delivered. My question is: Is this possible with Swift? Or does the `locationManager` function I'm using only work if the app is backgrounded, but not terminated?

**Side note:** I've tried taking out `if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background` and it does not fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you terminate the app, the normal* location services stop, until you run `startUpdatingLocation` from a non-background state.

---

*visit Location Service, region monitoring, significant Location Changes are **not** normal location tracking and are managed on the OS level not app level.

Non-normal location tracking won't get stopped after app termination.

Comment: How do you run `startUpdatingLocation` from a non-background state, i.e., when the app is terminated?

Comment: What is a non-background state to you? how do you think you get to such a state?

Comment: Such as when the app is terminated, when the user fully closes out of the app

Comment: You would only be able to do that when app is in foreground. Or was *launched* in the background (e.g. through entering a geofence, or getting a SLC callback)

Comment: If I understand correctly, `didUpdateLocations` will _not_ be called if the app is terminated and the location changes? It'll only be called if the app is open?

Comment: If you open the app again, you need some place in your app to have `startUpdatingLocation` called, otherwise simply because your in foreground it won't magically turn on. You have to tell it!

Comment: Sure, I have that in `viewDidLoad`. Do I need to put it somewhere else? `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`? But would this then be called if the app is terminated?

Comment: if you want it start when your app "was *launched* in the background" then you must put it inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Otherwise `viewDidLoad` would only be reached when app is in foreground. It's a business choice.

Comment: Ok, that was the problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

That's possible. Move the app so that location updates gets triggered. Check with accuracy as 100m and move your device or use simulator simulation for location. I am assuming that you have already given Use Location Always Permission

Comment: Yes, I have. I've had the simulator do the "highway drive", which works if the app is backgrounded but not terminated, but when it is terminated, the notifications stop getting delivered.

Comment: For simulator, the debugger gets disconnected. Have you tried the device ?

Comment: Since the debugger gets terminated, the highway drive gets terminated too. Run another app on same simulator and simulate location from that application.